# How to disable USB mass storage for normal user accounts?

Tags: windows-xp, usb, user-accounts

How do I disable the USB mass storage only on a user account? It should be enabled on an Administrator's account.

I am using Windows XP Professional Service Pack 2.

Comment: Which Windows version are you using?

Comment: sorry i forgot ..i have windows xp pro sp2

Answer (score 3):

If you're on windows, then you have to edit group policy settings to restrict users from accessing USB. You've to login as administrator to do these changes. Check [this](https://superuser.com/questions/134066/how-to-apply-group-policy-settings-to-specific-local-accounts-in-windows) question.

Comment: To add to Ryu's answer, see this question as well: http://superuser.com/questions/30669/how-to-enable-or-disable-usb-ports-on-windows-vista-pc

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you can try [USB Disable Pro](http://www.intelliadmin.com/index.php/usb-disabler-pro/), which allows enabling USB drive access to accounts with full admin access on the system.

There's a free version but (I think) it has to be run on the actual PC you need to disable the USB access on.

[image: screenshot]